# How to achieve a card slide in animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please take a look at the following basic example:

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: pink;
    float: left;
}

.students-list {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
    <a href="#">Students List</a>
</div>

<div class="students-list">
    
</div>
```

The pink div is a sidebar with a link. at first the second div which is the skyblue one, should be hidden, and when the user clicks on the link the whole div should slide smoothly from the left (From underneath the pink div).

Do any of you have a tip or can help me out how to achieve the animation?

EDIT: Is it possible to also use another button to slide out even a third div to the right of the second div?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below code

```css
body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

main {
  padding: 40px 25px;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  background: #36a;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #666;
  height: 100%;
  left: -17.5rem;
  padding-top: 38px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  width: 17rem;
  user-select: none;
}

nav a {
  color: #eee;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  transition: .5s;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: #39c;
}

#nav-collapse {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#nav-expand {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #eee;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none;  
  transition: .5s linear;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
}

#nav-expand:focus {
  opacity: 0;
}

#nav-expand:focus ~ main {
  margin-left: 17rem;
  transition-delay: .25s;
}

#nav-expand:focus ~ nav {
  left: 0;
  transition-delay: .25s;
}

#nav-expand:hover {
  background-color: #369;
  color: #fff;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
}

.icon-cross {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAALCAYAAACprHcmAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAPdJREFUGJV1jz9LhWAYxc+9rVZDQ+DcEI0NLU19gxr6Ci3tuvjnA+gggSBt4qzzO90b5FBubkHgEM1CBL5K93Ia8jWv4G88/A7PeQAArusekXwRQpiGYSzQ4/v+Gcn3OI6vMRJf+cdWFXrxs8+bOI5vkCTJLckf/rMtiuJhJJIk67oWAIA0Te8mhR2klGvbtg/UvNlC27ZPSlwquaqqZwA1dmGe56uu676HxPO8U5IfMyuGp+fEt+nTQghzqWnaMYBDdUVKuXYc5yLLsnsAmz5e6Lp+AgCIouiK5FfTNCvLsvanT5dl+Wia5t6wOwiC87GoCMPwUom/I2EVwEqOzwUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
}

.icon-menu {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAwAAAAMCAYAAABWdVznAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAB5JREFUKJFj/P///38GEgATKYoHKWAc9TQRgGRPAwD0IAv+FT8LPwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
}
```

```html
<a id="nav-expand" href="#">
  <span class="icon icon-menu"></span>&nbsp;
  Menu
</a>
<nav>
  <a id="nav-collapse" href="#">
    <span class="icon icon-cross"></span>
  </a>
  <a href="#">Link1</a>
  <a href="#">Link2</a>
  <a href="#">Link3</a>
  <a href="#">Link4</a>
</nav>
<main>
  <h2>Push Sidebar Exmaple</h2>
  <p>Please click on menu button.</p>
</main>
```

Comment: The code looks good, thanks for sharing it! But it is not exactly what I want.

EDIT: What I had in mind was not a side navigation, instead a div the slides out from below another div.

So we have box1
When I click on a button 
box2 slides out to the right of box2
and when I click on another button
box3 slides out to the right of box2.

Comment: So ideally, that should not be a push menu. It should be an overlay and on overlay should have sub-menues. Otherwise if sub-menues increase then it will squeeze the main content.

Comment: They won't increase, and even if they do, I am planning on hiding a couple in order to show new ones.

Are there any examples online on this behavior?

Comment: Hi @DavidMiller, I guess you are looking something like this. [Demo](https://tympanus.net/Development/MultiLevelPushMenu/#) , and link for [Code Sample](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/13/multi-level-push-menu/)